# Find the maximal radius of a inscribed circle

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

**Question:**

> How to find the exact value of the maximum radius of a inscribed circle between the curves $\sin x$ and $\cos x+1$ shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqxgQ.png).

I am interested in the inscribed circle between $-\pi$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: The two curves meet at $(-\pi,0)$ and $\left(\pi/2,1\right)$ and the region enclosed by such curves is symmetric with respect to the point $\left(-\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{1}{2}\right)$. Such point looks like the optimal candidate for the centre of the maximal inscribed circle.